# react-big-calendar navigate to specific day

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-big-calendar

it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am new to react . Actually , current `React-big-calendar` support navigate to specific date which are selected from Month view . I want same thing when user click on day from Month view I want to navigate user to specific day . please help me

**Code**

```
<MyCalendar
      popup
      selectable
      timeslots={1}
      localizer={localizer}
      view={this.state.viewing}
      views={[this.state.viewing]}
      components={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
      style={{ height: 600 }}
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
      min={new Date(2019, 10, 0, 7, 0, 0)}
      max={new Date(2019, 10, 0, 22, 0, 0)}
      events={this.props.events}
      eventPropGetter={this.eventStyleGetter}
      onSelectEvent={slotInfo => this.onSelectEventHandler(slotInfo)}
      onSelectSlot={slotInfo => this.onSelectEventSlotHandler(slotInfo)}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, they can already do this. Not by clicking on the entire date cell (which is used for selection), but by clicking on the 'date' number in the cell. Doing so will automatically transition the user to that date's 'day' view, unless you change the configuration.